# Angular 2: *ngFor variant

Tags: angular2-directives

What is the difference between : `*ngFor='let n in list'` and `*ngFor='let n of list'`
I just recently stumbled upon it. Searched through some old questions couldn't find any satisfactory answer.

Comment: Read this document it may help you https://medium.com/@jsayol/having-fun-with-angular-extending-ngfor-to-support-for-in-f30c724967ed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax

```
*ngFor='let n in list'
```

is not valid Angular syntax.

To prove it, creating a new angular project with a minimal `app.component.ts` file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let n in list">{{n}}</li>
  </ul>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  public list = [1,2,3,4,5];
}
```

Results in the error

```
compiler.js:486 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngForIn' since it isn't a known property of 'li'. ("
  <ul>
    <li [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let n in list">{{n}}</li>
  </ul>
  "): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@2:8
Property binding ngForIn not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("
  <ul>
    [ERROR ->]<li *ngFor="let n in list">{{n}}</li>
  </ul>
```

You can however create a custom directive to handle this (as mentioned in [this article](https://medium.com/@jsayol/having-fun-with-angular-extending-ngfor-to-support-for-in-f30c724967ed)).

As for the difference between of and in the article mentions the following:

> NgFor is Angular’s equivalent of the for…of statement in JavaScript, looping over an iterable object and taking each of its values one by one. There’s also the for…in statement which instead iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, but there’s no Angular equivalent to that, so let’s make one.

Answer (score 1):

> in JavaScript

for…in statement which instead iterates over the enumerable properties of an object

and

for…of statement looping over an iterable object taking each of its values one by one